# Removing Duplicates

Tags: bash

I have 2 folders in this situation, /ParentFolder/FolderName/Files.mp4 and /Mount/FolderName/Files.mp4.

In essence anything in /ParentFolder needs to replace any folders with the same name in /mount. I have to use ACDCLI for the actual copy so I need to remove these first by calling any folder name from /ParentFolder/* and rm -rf /mount/"FolderName"

If it was one folder easy, but I'm not sure how to say, get all the folder names from X, and delete if they exist in Y.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after.  But to get all of the folder names in X, you could do:

```
find /some/directory -type d -print
```

Repeat this in Y.  Of course, if the two directories are:  `/ParentFolder/FolderName/Files.mp4` and `/Mount/FolderName/Files.mp4`, then make sure you `cd` far enough so that you've moved passed the part of the paths that differ.

So, in the first directory, `cd` into `/ParentFolder`.  In the second case, `cd` into `/Mount`.

If you do this in both directories, you will get two lists (let's call them `list1.txt` and `list2.txt`), you can concatenate them, sort, and then print unique lines:

```
cat list1.txt list2.txt | sort | uniq -u
```

These are the directories that exist in only one list.  You can store this in a variable:

```
unique_paths=`cat list1.txt list2.txt | sort | uniq -u | xargs`
```

and then iterate through:

```
for my_path in ${unique_paths} ; do
  if [ -e "/ParentFolder/${my_path}" ] ; then
    ##  Do something to it
  else
    ##  This means it is in /Mount/, so do something else
  fi
done
```

I haven't tried this myself -- so do test it first.

As an alternative, you might want to look into the man pages of rsync.  Some combination of its options might achieve what you want.